# World map overlay on level plot

Tags: r, rworldmap

I am trying to place a world map on my current plots made by level plot. This plot was made as follows:

```
library(raster)
library(ncdf4)
library(maps)
library(maptools)
library(rasterVis)
library(ggplot2)
library(rgdal)
library(sp)
library(gridExtra)

MFplot4<-levelplot(MFMeaner3,margin=F, at=Fcutpoints4,cuts=11, 
pretty=TRUE,par.settings=mapTheme, main="Historical five-day maximum   
precipitation (mm/day) model mean")
```

The object "MFMeaner3" has the following attributes:

```
class       : RasterLayer 
dimensions  : 64, 128, 8192  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution  : 2.8125, 2.789327  (x, y)
extent      : -181.4062, 178.5938, -89.25846, 89.25846  (xmin, xmax, ymin, 
ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
data source : in memory
names       : layer 
values      : 0.1583802, 164.2064  (min, max)
```

Here was my attempt to place a world map overlay on the above plot:

```
world.outlines<-map("world", plot=FALSE) 
world.outlines.sp<-map2SpatialLines(world.outlines,proj4string =   
CRS("+proj=longlat"))
MFplot4 + layer(sp.lines(world.outlines.sp,col="black",lwd=0.5))
```

However, this leads to the following error:

```
Error: Attempted to create layer with no stat.
```

I also tried placing a simple world map using this:

```
MFplot4 + plot(wrld_simpl)
```

But I receive this error:

```
Error in UseMethod("as.layer") : 
no applicable method for 'as.layer' applied to an object of class "NULL"
```

Why would these errors occur?

Any assistance with this would be extremely appreciated!

Comment: @Josh O'Brien  Thanks for your response. Okay, I placed all packages used in the above post as an edit. :)

Comment: Still not reproducible without an example raster.  You can generate a dummy one using code - see https://stackoverflow.com/a/5963379/2761575

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is that, by loading **ggplot2**, you have masked the `latticeExtra::layer()` function (attached by **rasterVis**) with `ggplot2::layer()`. If you must load **ggplot2**, then you'll want to fully qualify your call to the masked function, writing `latticeExtra::layer()` in place of `layer()`.

Here is a reproducible example that works for me when **ggplot** is not loaded, but fails when it is:

```
library(rasterVis)
library(sp)
library(maps)
library(maptools)
## library(ggplot2)  ## `levelplot() + layer()` fails when this is loaded

## Read in a RasterLayer
tmax <- getData('worldclim', var='tmax', res=10)[[6]]

## Create a SpatialLines object
countries <- map("world", plot=FALSE) 
countries <- map2SpatialLines(countries, proj4string = CRS("+proj=longlat"))

## Overlay lines on levelplot
levelplot(tmax, margin=FALSE) + 
    layer(sp.lines(countries))
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Josh O'Brien Thank you for this response! I tried what you showed above, but I still receive this error: "Attempted to create layer with no stat" Why could this be? Maybe an error with the layer function?

Comment: Hi. Did you run this in a new session without loading **ggplot2**? I'd wager good money that you **do** have **ggplot** loaded or attached, since that error message about `"Attempted to create layer with no stat"` comes from **ggplot2**, which uses "stat"s... (To check whether it's not loaded, or at least not masking `latticeExtra::layer()`, run `find("layer")` and see what it gives you.)

Comment: Ah, that works!!!! You nailed the problem right on the head. Indeed, I just replaced "layer" with "latticeExtra::layer(), and it went through just fine!! Thank you so, so much!

And just to show what find("layer") returned: "package:ggplot2"      "package:latticeExtra"

Comment: @Android17 Good to hear. Glad that fixed it for you!